# How can I keep my Capacitor Plugin connected to an android package's foreground service on app destroy?

Tags: android, capacitor, foreground-service, capacitor-plugin

I'm writing a Capacitor Plugin that uses a native Android package which starts a foreground service. The Capacitor Plugin has listeners connected to the Android package for periodic updates.

While the app is in the foreground or background, the listener works and the capacitor app receives the listener callbacks.

But when the app is swiped away, the foreground service of the android package is still alive (notification status bar is active and I still see "notifying listeners" in the logs), but the capacitor plugin no longer receives any listener callbacks.

I was looking into if I need to create a bound service from the capacitor plugin to the android package somehow? Or how else can I keep the capacitor app alive while the native package's foreground service is alive

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services

The android package calls `startForegroundService(intent.extras)` internally, but the foreground service class is not exposed by the package

In the capacitor plugin javascript the listeners look like

```
export interface MyPlugin {
  addListener(eventName: 'events', listenerFunc: (result: { events: Event[] }) => void): Promise<PluginListenerHandle> & PluginListenerHandle;
  ...
}
```

and in the capacitor plugin android code

```
public class MyPlugin extends Plugin {

    private static final String TAG = "MyPlugin";
    protected static MyPlugin sPlugin;

    @Override
    public void load() {
        sPlugin = this;

        MyPackage.setReceiver(new MyPackageReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onEventsReceived(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Event[] events) {
                if (sPlugin == null) {
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    JSObject ret = new JSObject();
                    ret.put("events", events);
                    sPlugin.notifyListeners("events", ret);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.